# How to handle blocking calls / while 1-s, inside a tkinter's mainloop? ZMQ / Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, zeromq, pyzmq

I am using ZeroMQ, which is a messaging library (presumably async I/O), if you don't know what it is you can think of it as similar to socket library in python, the sockets used for messaging are usually run within an infinite while loop with a small sleep for keep everything cool.

I have the code written in a separate file and I have a GUI based on the working of that code separate, I want to integrate the two codes.

But the issue I come across is that I can not possibly put a **`while True`**, or a blocking **`socket.recv()`** inside **`tkinter`**'s **`.mainloop()`**.

I want to receive on on a socket, which is blocking - BUT I can manage that part of the issue, **`zmq`** sockets can either be polled on (check periodically to see if we have any pending messages to process) or equivalently you can use **`zmq.DONTWAIT`** which does the same thing.

The issue remaining however is that I need a **`while True`**, so that the socket is constantly polled, say every millisecond to see if we have messages.

How do I put a `while True` inside the `tkinter` **`.mainloop()`** that allows me to check the state of that socket constantly?

I would visualize something like this :

```
while True:    
    update_gui()       # contains the mainloop and all GUI code
    check_socket()     # listener socket for incoming traffic
    if work:
        #              # do a work, while GUI will hang for a bit.
```

I have checked the internet, and came across solution on SO, which says that you can use the After property of widgets but I am not sure how that works. If someone could help me out I would be super grateful !

**Code for reference :**

`zmq.DONTWAIT` throws an exception if you do not have any pending messages which makes us move forward in the loop.

```
while 1:
    if socket_listen and int(share_state):
        try:
            msg =  socket_listen.recv_string(zmq.DONTWAIT)
        except:
            pass

    time.sleep(0.01)
```

I would like that I could put this inside the `.mainloop()` and along with the GUI this also gets checked every iteration.

**Additional info :** Polling here equates to :

- check if we have messages on socket1
- if not then proceed normally
- else do work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I put a **`while True`** inside the **`tkinter`** **`.mainloop()`** that allows me to check the state of that socket constantly?

Do not design such part using an explicit **`while True`**-loop, better use the `tkinter`-native tooling: asking **`.after()`** to re-submit the call not later than a certain amount of time ( let for other things to happen concurrently, yet having a reasonable amount of certainty, your requested call will still be activated no later than "after" specified amount of milliseconds ).

---

### I love `Tkinter` architecture of co-existing event processing

So if one keeps the Finite-State-Automata ( a game, or a GUI front-end ) clean crafted on the `Tkinter`-grounds, one can enjoy delivering ZeroMQ-messages data being coordinated "behind" the scene, right by `Tkinter`-native tools, so no imperative-code will be needed whatsoever. Just let the messages get translated into **`tkinter`**-monitored-variables, if you need to have indeed smart-working GUI integration.

```
aScheduledTaskID = aGuiRelatedOBJECT.after( msecs_to_wait,
                                            aFunc_to_call = None,
                                            *args
                                            )
# -> <_ID_#_>
# ... guarantees a given wait-time + just a one, soloist-call
#     after a delay of at least delay_ms milliseconds.
#     There is no upper limit to how long it will actually take, but
#     your callback-FUN will be called NO SOONER than you requested,
#     and it will be called only once.
#     aFunc_to_call() may "renew" with .after()
#
# .after_cancel( aScheduledTaskID )  # <- <id> CANCELLED from SCHEDULER
#
# .after_idle() ~ SCHEDULE A TASK TO BE CALLED UPON .mainloop() TURNED-IDLE
#
#     aScheduledTaskOnIdleID = aGuiOBJECT.after_idle( aFunc_to_call = None,
#                                                     *args
#                                                     )
# -> <_ID_#_>
```

That's cool on using the ready-to-reuse **`tkinter`** native-infrastructure scheduler tools in a smart way, isn't it?

---

### Epilogue:

> ( ***Blocking* calls?** Better never use blocking calls at all. Have anyone ever said blocking calls here? **`:o)`** )

---

> a **`while True`**, or a blocking **`socket.recv()`** inside `tkinter`'s **`.mainloop()`**.

well, one can put such a loop into a component aligned with **`tkinter`** native-infrastructure scheduler, yet this idea is actually an antipattern and can turn things into wreck havoc ( not only for `tkinter`, in general in any event-loop handler it is a bit risky to expect any "competitive" event-handler loop to somehow tolerate or behave in a peacefull the co-existence of adjacent intentions - problems will appear ( be it from a straight blocking or due to one being a just too much dominant in scheduling resources or other sorts of a war on time and resources ) ).

Comment: thank you very much for the detailed reply, i will use .after() function instead - which is i presume tkinters personal while loop, but it avoids race conditions in the code. 
correct me if am wrong.

Comment: Always welcome, Sir. The `tkinter` native `.after()` method is nothing but a one-time-request to call something "after" a given delay since the call. Thus do not expect a hardwired `while True`, but a one-time-shot. The trick is to "renew" ( typically in-call ) the same "subscription" to a next `self.after(...)` before the called handler finishes. This self-chaining of `.after()` calls ought be linear and keeps the flow as if there were a concurrent code-execution path "inside" a `while True` code-block. The other option **`.after_idle()`** can help to defer calls that need not timed schedules